# network adapter could not establish connection in tomcat

Tags: java, jdbc, tomcat7

I have this simple jsp page with a button. On clicking it passes to a servlet which calls a database function,retrieves value from db and returns the value back to the jsp and displays it. This project works fine in netbeans using glassfish. Now i have a server in OCI. downloaded apache tomcat 8 from the internet and unzipped it in the home folder of this oci server and deployed this project in webapps folder -the jsp retrieves and displays data fine. Everything is fine. Now in the same server i installed another tomcat using yum command and it got installed in the root. So here when i click on the button the data retrival doesnt work. As soon as i click on the button in the jsp it throws error "SEVERE: SQLException while connecting to dbjava.sql.SQLException: Io exception: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection". I have no idea why is this simple connection not being established only in this root installed tomcat. I am new to tomcat. I couldnt find an answer online. Found the path also weird as below.
log path:-/var/log/tomcat
webapps path:/var/lib/tomcat/webapps.
I am using jdbc thin connection.
jdbc:oracle:thin:@xxx.xx.xx.xx:1521:aaaaa

Answer (score 0):

Judging fron the exception infomation,your app server is not connect to database server,so you should check the app server is connect to your database server。

Comment: please use the comments section for sharing suggestions.

Comment: I could access it from the tomcat installed in the home folder of the same server..moreover telnet to the db is also fine.